# How to trigger render() method when navigating back with `react-navigation`?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

I have a simple app with two screens inside a `StackNavigator`:

```
export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Main: { screen: MainPage },
    ChooseColor: { screen: ChooseColorPage }
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'Main',
});
```

Upon pressing a button, the app navigates to `ChooseColorPage`:

```
class MainPage extends Component {

    onChooseColor() {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        navigation.navigate('ChooseColor', {});
    }
}
```

Then, the user can choose a color by pressing a button, which triggers a navigation back to the `MainPage`:

```
class ChooseColorPage extends Component {

    onSelectColor(colorKey) {
        // this updates the state inside a `ColorReducer`
        this.props.colorChanged({ colorKey });
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        navigation.goBack();
    }
}
```

I want the `MainPage` to update based on the chosen color, however **the `render()` method is not called on back navigation**.

**Question**: Under which cases is the `render()` method called when navigating between screens with `react-navigation`?

I would have assumed that updating the state in the `ColorReducer` would have been enough to trigger a `render()` call in `MainPage` but this does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is not a navigation problem, but a state management problem.

I was incorrectly setting up `mapStateToProps` on my MainPage. After adding this, `render()` is called as a result of a navigation update.

My app reducer:

```
const AppReducer = combineReducers({
  color: ColorReducer,
  nav: NavReducer,
});
```

My `ColorReducer`:

```
const initialState = {
    colorKey: null,
};

const ColorReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'COLOR_CHANGED':
            return { ...state, colorKey: action.payload.colorKey };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

My `mapStateToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { colorKey: state.color.colorKey };
};
```